# Ajax Request Timeout but data has update on server

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have Problem with ajax Call

this is my Code

```
$.ajax({
beforeSend: function(x) {                   
if(x && x.overrideMimeType) {
x.overrideMimeType("application/j-son;charset=UTF-8");                          }                                               
},
data:{id : myid},
url: 'xxx.org/myphp.php',
cache: false,
headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'},
type: 'POST',       
success: function(rsp) {
alert(rsp)                   
},timeout: 10000,
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    if(textStatus === 'timeout'){               
    alert('timeout')
    }else{
    Alert(textStatus,"Connection Lost, Check Our Connection");      
    }
}})
```

sometimes this request have timeout but the data on a server side have update..
how to explain this and what the solution for this case...

what i wan is when request is timeout then abort the proses update data..
any idea??